# Unable to resolve System.EnterpriseServices.Wrapper.dll when using SqlDateTime.MinValue

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, sqldatetime

Whenever I use "System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime.MinValue.Value" in my xamarin.forms app I am getting the following error while building my IOS App

```
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(700,3): error : Can not resolve reference: /Users/Krishna/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/Sthotraani.iOS/c0a19cab5e3651bee11740ffa8f7047b/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/System.EnterpriseServices.Wrapper.dll
```

The moment I remove this the error disappears, could somebody help me find the root cause